# Is it ok to have files owned by a non-existent user?

Tags: permissions, users, nfs

I have a server A with a mounted volume that is shared via NFS with server B and C.

If I create a file on that volume using a user X in group Y that only exists on server A, will that create any problems with the sharing of that file through NFS? Will server B and server C be able to read the file ok if the 3rd party permissions including reading?

Comment: There should be a mechanism that maps UIDs from the NFS server to the clients.  The exact mechanism depends on your system.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's fine.

UNIX doesn't really care about names.  For file permissions, it's the numbers that are important; when you try to access the file, it'll see if your UID matches, then GID, then it'll use the "other" permissions.  As long as the "other" permissions include reading, you'll be able to read those files.

It doesn't check to see if a user or group exists for that number unless you're running something like `ls` that shows user and group names (in which case, it'll just show the number).

On my home server I have many UIDs and GIDs that do not exist on any other machines; NFS handles it just fine.  FreeBSD server, OpenBSD and Linux clients.

Comment: Keep in mind that, when using NFSv3, access is matched using UID/GID. This means that if a user on a client exist with the same UID as on the source server, this user can have more access than desired. You can force read-only access by configuring the export accordingly.

Comment: With NFSv4 access is matched using userid-name mapping. This means that although UIDs can differ for a specific user on some machines, that user can still have the proper access because the username will be matched.

Comment: I've played with NFSv4 in the past but never knew that.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

Having files owned by a non-existent user won't cause any immediate problems. As far as the kernel is concerned, there's no concept of users existing, just a numerical user ID. As far as higher levels are concerned, a particular user ID might have no user name associated to it, which is unusual but not in itself problematic.

The risk with files owned by a non-existent user is that if you create an account, it might get that user ID. Since there's no account by that ID, the ID is free; the fact that files exists with that user ID doesn't affect this. (What if the files were on a removable drive or network filesystem that isn't currently mounted? The OS would have no way to do this.)

In your distributed setup, this should be ok. Servers B and C should be configured not to use the same user ID ranges as server A anyway, to avoid clashes with existing users, except for users who don't own files on A's NFS shares.

Comment: Is there any network protocol that helps distribute IDs?

Comment: Yes, there's NIS.  It's old and insecure, but it works on pretty much any UNIX.  It's pretty much the companion protocol to NFS.  It's possible to migrate your user and group databases to LDAP (throw in Kerberos, and you can have an Active Directory-like setup).  Then there's stuff like puppet that allows you to maintain system configurations for multiple machines in one place.